# What is the meaning of field mValid in GpsSatellite?

Tags: android, gps, android-location, nmea

There is a field in the class `GpsSatellite` called `mValid` with type boolean. I would assume that this is set based on whether the satellite is healthy and can be used reliably by the receiver. This assumption is based on what I know about GPS, but I don't know much about the internals of Android to say for sure if this is correct.

GPS almanac messages contain information about the health of each satellite in the constellation. These are visible for example in the NMEA sentences output by most receivers. Am I correct in assuming that the field `mValid` is related to whether or not the satellite in question is healthy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No your assumption is not correct. This has nothing to do with healthy info.

GpsSattelite are stored in an Array of ids.
Once SatInfo for a specifc sat is received, that array is updated and flag `mValid` is set.

See source code of method [setStatus()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/eclair-passion-release/location/java/android/location/GpsStatus.java)

Comment: Ok, thanks! BTW, a semi-related question. Do you know in which source code file the elevation and azimuth angles are actually calculated? Or is this output directly from the GPS receiver?

Comment: Of course this comes directly from the receiver. This is for example contained. in the NMEA GPGSV messages. You might read also the free book: GPS Essentials of Satelllte Navigation from ublox homepage

Comment: Ok, I thought so. I would love to see where in the Android source the data is actually retrieved from the receiver. I know I can parse NMEA sentences, but I would like to understand how Android actually gets this data and makes it available in the API.

Comment: I think this is done in a driver. I saw one from Qualcom GPS. This is probly not done in availabe source. But for sure it comes from the chip itself, without any modificition.

Comment: But there must be an "entry point" in the available source, right?